# Tableau: Error while using Impala to connect to Cloudera Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, tableau-api, impala

I am working on using Tableau to connect to Cloudera Hadoop. I provide the server and port details and connect using "Impala". I am able to succesfully connect, select default Schema and choose the required table (s).

After this, when I drag and drop either a dimension or a measure to Rows/Columns on the 'grid', i get the below error:

[Cloudera][Hardy] (22) Error from ThriftHiveClient: Query returned non-zero code: 10025, cause: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key '`<column name>`'.

However, if i try the same using the connection type as 'HiveServer' (not 'Impala'), it works fine. We are not sure where we are going wrong.

Any help on this is very much appreciated?

Thanks.

Regards,
Sudhakar

Comment: Which versions of Impala and the Cloudera ODBC driver are being used?

Comment: Cloudera ODBC Driver 2.5 for Impala. Impala version is 1.2.3 which is part of CDH 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is because [the Cloudera ODBC 2.5 driver is not currently supported for Impala](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/issue/error-unable-to-connect-to-server-cloudera-impala) .

To resolve the issue, uninstall the Cloudera ODBC 2.5 driver and install the Cloudera ODBC 1.2 driver instead.

Comment: Thanks Talvalin. This change worked. Also to be noted is that i need to use port 21000 for Impala. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3031097 Hi, I ran into exactly the same problem and can you show us how you uninstalled the driver for ODBC2.5? Also, when I tried to connect to impala, I have to use port 10000 and credential of my hue environment... don't know why 25010 not working.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Tableau Pro 10.4.3 and Impala ODBC Connector 2.5.41 64-bit on Win 10. 
After uninstalling Impala connector and installing Hive ODBC Driver 2.5.25 everything got fixed but i had to edit connection in Tableau to set type to HiveServer2 and auth by username for hive.