# Error: Expression not in Group BY key when using Tableau to query Impala on Cloduera

Tags: hadoop, tableau-api, cloudera-cdh, impala

We're running Cloudera 5.9, Tableau 10.1, and the Impala ODBC connector version 2.5.35 (though I've tried a bunch of versions).  When setting up the Tableau connection to Cloudera Hadoop, I'm using port 10000 (no idea if that is correct) to type Impala.  I can see the various tables in Impala and a handful of rows from those tables.  When I do a simple query in a workbook, I hit this error:

[Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [42000] : Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'bar'

It is generating this query, which works fine when I run it in impala-shell:

SELECT foo.bar AS bar
FROM default.foo foo
GROUP BY 1

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258045/tableau-error-while-using-impala-to-connect-to-cloudera-hadoop) but that is 2 years old and Cloudera claims [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_odbc.html) that they are compatible as of late 2015.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bunch of combinations and installing various drivers, it looks like using port: 10000 Type: HIveServer2 and installing the Hive ODBC driver from http://www.cloudera.com/downloads.html works.  I don't understand how that is different from the Imapala connection type or if it is limiting what Tableau can do.